# Parameter in custom SQL query taking forever in Computing view layout

Tags: tableau-api

I have a custom sql query from oracle DB using live connection. Following query returns the results in less than a second. When I pull the columns in the Tableau sheet, I get the layout quickly.

```
SELECT COLUMN_A,
  FROM TABLE_A ss, TABLE_B sc, TABLE_C pse, TABLE_D ps
WHERE  ss.hnspartnerid = sc.swcustomerid
and sc.COMPANY = 'AND'
and ss.SITE = pse.SRCSITE
and pse.SITE = ps.SITE
  AND ss.ACTTYPE <> 'Physical Location'
```

When I replace the value with the parameter to create the dynamic query, "Compute layout" is taking forever. I get the results in less than a second on the "Data Source" tab.

> ```
> SELECT COLUMN_A,   FROM TABLE_A ss, TABLE_B sc, TABLE_C pse, TABLE_D
> ps WHERE  ss.hnspartnerid = sc.swcustomerid and sc.COMPANY =<Parameters.CustomerID> and ss.SITE = pse.SRCSITE and pse.SITE =
> ps.SITE   AND ss.ACTTYPE <> 'Physical Location'
> ```

Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong? I believe Tableau executes the query after the user inputs the parameter. Is it executing the query before that and using parameter as a filter?

Comment: What fields do you have on the various shelves on your worksheet? What filters?